# Yii CDbCommand queryAll() return wrong result

Tags: php, yii, pdo

I'm using Yii CDbCommand to fetch result from mysql.
I log the SQL in mysql query and by var_dump Yii's CDbCommand SQL both.
It's the same.
I get the result by CDbCommand->queryAll().
But the result is not the same as of running the same SQL in phpMyAdmin.

```
> SELECT `referer_url_id` FROM `trend_referer` WHERE
> ((`site_id` = '45654' and `date` between '20131211' and '20131211'))
> GROUP BY `referer_url_id` LIMIT 6
> OFFSET 30;
```

This SQL. I get 6 result from queryAll and phpMyAdmin.
But only 3 of them are same. The other 3 are different.
It's weird.

**EDIT:**
The most weird thing is that afer several minute this problem disappear.
And occur in another 'LIMIT 6 OFFSET xx'.
xx is not the same all time.
So I think it's any cache mechanism in PDO or Yii?

Comment: try `(date` between '20131211' and '20131211')`

Comment: What kind of answer you expect? That queryAll fake some results returned from database?

Comment: `->queryAll()` does not magically rewrite your raw query to get different results. If you get different results when running the same query multiple times, it implies that something in your query (the result sort order) is not deterministic. Why are you using `GROUP BY` instead of `ORDER BY`? What does the table schema look like?

Comment: change it to `LIMIT 30, 6`

Comment: the result from phpMyAdmin is right. but queryAll() return the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT `referer_url_id` FROM `trend_referer` WHERE
((`site_id` = '45654' and (`date` between '20131211' and '20131211')) )
GROUP BY `referer_url_id` LIMIT 6
OFFSET 30;
```

add round brackets surround `date between '20131211' and '20131211'`

**EDIT:**

And for offset error 'LIMIT 6 OFFSET xx'.

change your query to

```
GROUP BY `referer_url_id` LIMIT 30, 6
```

Comment: that's not the sql problem. I get the 6 result and 3 of them are same and 3 are different by queryAll() and phpMyAdmin. The phpMyAdmin result is right. queryAll() return the wrong result.

Comment: change it to `LIMIT 30, 6`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43012/discussion-between-magic-and-zzlalani)

Answer (score -2):

I know what the issue. Because Yii CDbCommand.php's buildQuery() function that join the SQL use `"\n"` as line feed but not space.
For example.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY field;`

will become

```
SELECT *\nFROM table\nWHERE 1=1\nGROUP BY field;
```

That cause different result.
I modify buildQuery(). Replace the "\n" to space. That I can get the right result set.

I'm testing against MySQL-5.5.18-log version. I don't know whether it's a MySQL bug or Yii.

Comment: This is apparently not the issue. May be some sort of caching as you guessed before.